# ajax call works fine on my machine but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, call

The following code work fine when running on my development machine -

```
            $.ajax({
            url: 'services/chatEngine.asmx/addUser',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                UN: from,
                chatapplicationId: '222'
            },
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                usersScrollLocation = document.getElementById('userList').scrollTop;
                //alert('before');
            },
            fail: function () { alert('Error'); },
            complete: function () { alert('Done'); },
            success: function (a, b, c) {
                alert('success');
                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    try {
                        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(c.responseXML.lastChild.lastChild.data, "text/xml");
                    }
                    catch (e) { alert(e.Message) }
                }
                else // Internet Explorer
                {
                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = false;
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(c.responseXML.lastChild.lastChild.data);
                }
                //alert('b4 If');
                if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('user')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue != 'Error') {
                    var el = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('user')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    var t;
                    //if (el != from) {
                    t = '<span  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="newPrivateChat(\'' + el + '\');">' + el + '</span>' + '<br>';
                    //}
                    //else {
                    //    t = '<span><b>' + el + '</b></span>' + '<br>';
                    //}
                    $('#userList').append(t);
                    userok = true;

                }
            }

        });
```

The code is working fine on my machine but when running on server the ajax.success function is never called...

I cannot see what the problem is, please assist.

Thanks,

Comment: Any Errors? Does complete get called? Can you access the URL directly?

Comment: @Shai use fiddler and see what the response of the request is. it could help you figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the path is not the same on the server than in local, because of the Application/Virtual Folder Name. Open it on Chrome, and with the developer tools you can check on the network tab what's the real URL that it's trying to reach and maybe you will find out what you're missing